# The template cannot be rendered by Object in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

1. In this demo, (https://jsfiddle.net/ccforward/fa35a2cc/) I cannot render the template and the data `resultWrong` equals `{}`
2. In this demo, (https://jsfiddle.net/ccforward/zoo6xzck/), if I use a temporary variable to save the async data ,then I can get the result and render the template
3. If I add another function named as `getRightData()` in the methods, then the  `getWrongData()`  can work and the template can be rendered.
   link: https://jsfiddle.net/ccforward/7f42owpc/4/
4. If I delete the `getRightData()` method, then the `getWrongData()` cannot work.
   link:  https://jsfiddle.net/ccforward/7f42owpc/3/

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 1):

Vue [cannot detect properties that are added dynamically](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) to an object unless you add them using [set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Here is your first [fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/fa35a2cc/1/) to properly add properties to an empty object using `this.$set`.

For your demos, the first does not work because you add the properties using an index and Vue doesn't know that it needs to update the DOM.

The second demo works because the base value, `resultRight`, is set to a completely different value. `resultRight` is a reactive value and when it changes to a different value, Vue is aware that it needs to update the DOM.

The third demo *appears* to work, but it only works because `resultRight` changes, and because it is reactive, Vue knows to update the DOM. `resultWrong` is rendered at the same time but *only* because Vue rendered it based on the change in `resultRight`.

The fourth demo fails for the same reason the first demo failed. `resultWrong` gets new properties, but Vue doesn't *know* about those properties. And because you are not changing the object reference (as when you change `resultRight` to `tmp`), Vue doesn't have any idea it needs to update the DOM.

Comment: But I don't know why the third demo (https://jsfiddle.net/ccforward/7f42owpc/4/) can work ?

Comment: @ccForward The third demo doesn't quite work. It shows the data of `resultWrong` but they are not *reactive*. You can see if you log those values.

Comment: @ccForward Added some further explanation. Hopefully it clarifies.